# ViewModelFactory cant instantiate ViewModel correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have this error when I created my ViewModelFactory to pass my UseCase with the repository

### viewModelFactory

```
class LoginVMFactory(private val useCase: PostUserTokenImpl):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(PostUserTokenImpl::class.java).newInstance(useCase)
    }
}
```

### View

```
 private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginVMFactory(PostUserTokenImpl(UserRepoImpl()))).get(LoginViewModel::class.java) }
```

### ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel(private val useCase: PostUserToken): ViewModel() {
...
}
```

Error log

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class
>   com.test.domain.PostUserTokenImpl]
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
>           at com.test.presentation.viewmodel.LoginVMFactory.create(LoginVMFactory.kt:13)

Error log points to this

```
 return modelClass.getConstructor(PostUserTokenImpl::class.java).newInstance(useCase)
```

Comment: Can you share your `LoginViewModel` and its constructors?

Comment: looks like PostUserTokenImpl doesn't have a proper constructor

Comment: ViewModel added @ianhanniballake PostUserToken is an interface that is implemented in PostUserTokenImpl

Comment: I have posted the viewmodel @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

if you need some params in ViewModel, you can do follow me:

1.Create BaseViewModelFactory

```
class BaseViewModelFactory <T> (val creator: () -> T) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return creator() as T
    }
}
```

2.create 2 extenstion funtion (Kotlin) to create view model

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
    return if (creator == null) {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java)
    } else {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
    return if (creator == null) {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java)
    } else {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
    }
}
```

3. simple use

```
viewModel = getViewModel()
```

or

```
viewModel = getViewModel {
 LoginViewModel(usecase)
}
```